JPARepository @Query: Filtering out empty String[] values (PostgreSQL _text)
I have a PostgreSQL-database table with nullable _text column. In backend entity it is configured as String[].
@Type(StringArrayType.class)
@Column(
    name = "texts",
    columnDefinition = "text[]"
)
private String[] texts;

I'm trying to use JPARepository's @Query-annotation to find the latest entity with above column's values not empty or null, but haven't found a way to do it yet (one of the examples below).
@Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e " +
        "WHERE e.orderNo = 1 " +
        "AND e.texts IS NOT EMPTY " + // not working
        "ORDER BY e.createdAt DESC " +
        "LIMIT 1")
Optional<Entity> findLatestEntityWithTextsValues();

Is there a good way to filter out empty/null texts values in a query? I can always filter them later, but I'd rather get the result immediately as an Optional from the database instead of returning a List that then needs iteration.

Using a native sql for the query is a no-go? Alternatively, you can try to use Postgresql's array_length funcion (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).

I could probably use nativeQuery, but I've tried not to utilise it to keep everything consistent in JPA queries! But that could be a better solution to iterating if this way ends up not being possible.

Are you using Postgresql's TEXT because you need a clob style management? Or you may use a simpler data type, such as a VARCHAR or others?

It fit the purpose years ago and has lots of data, so I don't really want to change it anymore haha. In hindsight I'd use a separate table or something simpler, PostgreSQL array-types have not been my favourites...

Since you are already dealing with a Postgresql's type and syntax while declaring the texts attribute and column, perhaps using a native based query can solve your problem without too much impact on the other components of your application.
You can try to use the array_length function (see documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-array.html) and change the repository query accordingly:
"AND array_length(e.texts, 1) > 0 " +

Of course remember to adapt the class / attribute names that are used in the JPQL query to the table / column ones, and set the query as native (i.e. nativeQuery = true).
As an alternative (but I don't know if this works on fields that are managed by StringArrayType and are specified with columnDefinition attribute), I saw that also JPQL, using Hibernate 6.5.3.Final, can manage and transcode to native sql an array_length function, so that you can directly write in you query:
"AND array_length(e.texts) > 0 " +

In my tests on h2 or hsqldb, this is converted into the correct function for getting the size of the array (i.e. cardinality, in this case).

Thanks, I got the above one working! But apparently fetching lazy data is not possible through native query? I left out some LEFT JOIN FETCHs from the original post as they seemed irrelevant, but as we have some FetchType.LAZY on entity connections, we need to later get them from database... In this situation it's only one extra query thankfully.
If native-query fetching is indeed not possible, I wonder if it's faster/"green-coder" to iterate the list of results or to do the extra fetching call for the connected entity. CriteriaBuilder maybe could do both, but too much effort for this.

I think that iterate over a whole set of java items is very less than optimal; if you need to manage a fully context attached entity for getting the whole set of relations in hibenate way, you may choose to change the native query to extract just the unique id of the record that matches the empty texts constraints, then use that id to get through the "classic" findById the complete managed entity. I know that this means two database calls, but I suspect that this could be faster than filtering on java side.
